# Read sensor data from InputStream

Tags: java, stream, inputstream

In my application I receive Sensor data via bluetooth and I want to read it in an efficient way.
The data stream looks as follows:

`04 64 E2 FF 49` `04 64 E3 FF 4A` `04 64 E1 FF 48` `...` `...`

so, in this case `04` is the begin of a new data frame. (`04` depicts the number of the upcoming bytes)

I read the data stream using an InputStream Object.
How do I read the stream into a buffer to decode the bytes afterwards?
The problem is that `read(buffer,offset,length)` is not guaranteed to read `length` amount of bytes. Sometimes it's less than `length`. I gues reading the data byte for byte is inefficient.
What's the common approach to read decoded data from a input stream?

kind regards

Comment: You can use a `ByteBuffer` and `read` in a loop until the required number of bytes is read.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to create a small utility method that guarantees that it reads the number of bytes that you ask it to read:

```
public static void readFully(InputStream in, byte[] buffer, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
    int total = 0;
    while (total < length) {
        int r = in.read(buffer, offset + total, length - total);
        if (r < 0)
            throw new EOFException();
        total += r;
    }
}
```

You can probably find something like this is in the *apache-commons-io* library.

Comment: I see, Java also contains a `DataInputStream.readFully()` method. I'll try this one. Nevertheless, is it common to read each data frame seperately or should i read more frames at once in a buffer and then extract each frame again later?

Comment: Just read the bytes as you need them. To speed up reading by buffering, just wrap your InputStream in a `BufferedInputStream`

Comment: `DataInputStream.readFully` is not a static method; you can only use it if you have wrapped your InputStream in a `DataInputStream`. That's something I wouldn't do just to be able to invoke one method (if you need its other methods, then it does sound like a good idea). A static method like I posted is useful - you usually have a few classes with utility methods if you build a larger application.